# Which one to use? Swagger 1.5.x or 2.x?

Tags: java, swagger, resteasy, openapi

I am working on a new Java project that involves RESTful web services. Since the Swagger framework is quite popular nowadays, I decided to try it, but I am not really sure, which version to choose.

After a brief research I found out that Swagger 1.5.x produces Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 definitions and Swagger 2.x produces OpenAPI 3.0 definitions. However, I failed to find some deeper information about which version is "better" or which one to prefer and why.

It seems to me that there's a lot more information, articles, tutorials etc. about Swagger 1.5.x than there's about 2.x. On the other hand, 2.x is newer and implements newer specification of OpenAPI.

I don't know if it's important, but the application is a "small" (50 classes in total) multi-tier architecture, business logic is exposed via web services. I am using JBoss application server in combination with the RESTEasy technology.

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: For C#/dotnet Core, the answer is easy: just use whatever Swagger NuGet wants to give you.  SUGGESTION: Try both (separate copies of the same project).  If the newer version is easy to use the works well, go for it!  PS: Are you familiar with this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api